# Unable to Read From Zipped XLS files using Python zipfile module

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xls, python-zipfile

I have a subroutine that takes a collection of outlook messages, saves the attached zip files as temporary files and reads the tabular data to pandas data frames. It seems to work fine for csv files and most excel files, but my function fails whenever there's a xls file stored within the attached zip folder in the message.

Here's two functions I'm using to read the files:

```
def isexcel(file):
    #evaluates file path and return true if excel file. otherwise returns false
    extension = os.path.splitext(file.filename)[1]
    if extension in ['.xls','.xlsx','.xlsm','.xlsb','.odf','.odt','.ods']:
        return True 
    else: 
        return False

def zipattach_to_dfs(attachment, extract_fn=None):
    #evaluates zip file attachments and returns dictionary with file name as key and dataframes as values
    df_objects = {}
    with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp:
        attachment.SaveAsFile(tmp.name)
        zf = ZipFile(tmp, mode = 'a')
        for file in zf.infolist():
            key = (f'{file.filename} ({"-".join(map(str, file.date_time[:3]))})')
            if isexcel(file) ==True:
                temp_df = pd.read_excel(zf.open(file.filename), header=None)
                df_objects.update({key:temp_df})
            elif file.filename.endswith(".csv"):
                temp_df = pd.read_csv(zf.open(file.filename), header=None)
                df_objects.update({key:temp_df})
            else:
                raise NotImplementedError('Unexpected filetype: '+str(file.filename))
    return (df_objects)
```

I keep getting the error "File is Not a Zip File."

Has anyone seen anything like this before with an xls file? Is there any alternative way to read the data on these xls files to a pandas dataframe when its retrieved from a emailed zip folder?

Comment: Can you share that problematic ZIP file?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot sorry. But it doesn’t appear to be corrupted. It’s happening with any zip files that contain .xls files.

Comment: XLS is not a zipped archive, XLSX files (with an X) are the zipped archives.  XLS is the older single binary blob format.  Look at the first 2 bytes, they are not "PK"

Comment: Is there a way to test the contents of the zip folder and convert just the xls files to bytestream objects before passing to pandas?

Comment: If your code can look at the first four hex bytes you'll see "PK" \3 \4 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)

Comment: @Possdawgers, you don't seem to be very open to [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77191184/16120011). The error is clearly raised because at least one of the attachments is not a `ZipFile`. You need to add a check [`is_zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.is_zipfile). And site note, `mode = 'a'` make no sense in your context. I suggest you to remove it.

Comment: thanks, I am open to and appreciative of the feedback. I just took me entirely too long to figure out that xls files were being incorporated into the mix.